# In pandas how to turn rows into columns and assign the value of rows after?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python 3 and Pandas I have this dataframe:

```
prop_selec_cleaned.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 146322 entries, 0 to 146321
Data columns (total 2 columns):
codigo_unico    146322 non-null object
words_array     146322 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 3.3+ MB

prop_selec_cleaned.reset_index().head()
index   codigo_unico            words_array
0   0   MSC 36/2010 - 465465    [comunica, o, excelentíssimo, senhor, presiden...
1   1   MPV 480/2010 - 465466   [abre, crédito, extraordinário, em, favor, da,...
2   2   MSC 38/2010 - 465467    [comunica, o, excelentíssimo, senhor, presiden...
3   3   MSC 42/2010 - 465469    [submete, à, deliberação, do, congresso, nacio...
4   4   PL 6720/2010 - 465470   [concede, auxílio, especial, e, bolsa, especia...
```

I need to create a new dataframe in which the columns are the "codigo_unico" rows. And the rows in each column will be the lines of "words_array"

Something like:

```
MSC 36/2010 - 465465                                MPV 480/2010 - 465466                               MSC 38/2010 - 465467
[comunica, o, excelentíssimo, senhor, presiden...   [abre, crédito, extraordinário, em, favor, da,...   [comunica, o, excelentíssimo, senhor, presiden...
```

So it would be a dataframe with 146,322 columns (the "codigo_unico") and only one line (filled with the "words_array")

Please, does anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor with convert column to `1d` numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([prop_selec_cleaned['words_array'].values],
                   columns=prop_selec_cleaned['codigo_unico'])
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(prop_selec_cleaned['words_array'].values[None,:],
                   columns=prop_selec_cleaned['codigo_unico'])
```

Or create index by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), convert `Series` to 1 column `DataFrame` by [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and last transpose:

```
df = prop_selec_cleaned.set_index('codigo_unico')['words_array'].to_frame().T
```